# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec ImportError: No module named 'encodings' after using py2exe

Tags: python-3.4, py2exe

I was using py2exe and testing my new program when this came up on the exe console screen:

Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

what should I do?

Comment: the real python works

Comment: It was after I moved the exe from the main python 3.4 dist file

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe py2exe is compatible with 3.X. Try out [PyInstaller](http://pyinstaller.org) instead.

Note: I am not affiliated with PyInstaller in any way, other than as a user.

Comment: I now know why, Py2exe DELETED all the code in the main python 3.4.3 executable